# How to embed an image into a quarto document in R

Tags: r

Iam having difficulty embedding an image into my quarto document in R. I converted my image from a jpg file intp a png file. After that I do not know what to do.

I tried to do this

```
![Star Guards](Hoop1.png)
```

however it did not work. Thank you
It does not seem like it should be a complicated process, I just do not know how to do it.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html, the syntax is:

```
![Elephant](path/to/elephant.png)
```

A common gotcha is that the working directory might not be what you expect.  In a code block, you can use `print(getwd())` to check what the working directory is when the output document is being generated.